# MediaWiki: Changing H1 size in `common.css'

Tags: mediawiki

I'm just learning MediaWiki (with limited PHP and CSS experience also), and am customizing my site's look with the "MediaWiki:common.css" page. I've previously used

```
h1 { color: #880000; }
```

to turn that header red. But entering

```
h1 { font-size: 10pt; }
```

or

```
h1 { font-size: 80%; }
```

has no effect. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having a link, or knowing what skin your're viewing your wiki in, it's hard to say for sure, but if you add the rules you mentioned to a vanilla install of MediaWiki, there will more specific CSS rules that override your font-size, e.g.

```
.mw-body h1, .mw-body #firstHeading {
  font-size: 1.8em;
}
```

You will have to use a more specific rule to override that one, e.g:

```
.mw-body h1, .mw-body #firstHeading {
  font-size: 10pt;
}
```

in your `MediaWiki:Common.css`. Also note that results may vary depending on what skin your users are using.

**edit:** Possible duplicate with any of these: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=CSS+specificity

Comment: Thank you---this code worked perfectly. I will also do some reading on "CSS specificity". This is a new term for me.